# Error : "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement" Insert and update in mariadb using Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mariadb, insert-update

I am inserting records in maria db table from a file using python. Input file has header. Some of the columns are fully or partial empty. I am trying below code -

Table Definition -

```
CREATE TABLE `local_db`.`table_x` (
  `Unique_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Govt` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
input_file = "C:\\Users\\input_file.csv"
csv_data = csv.reader(open(input_file))
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='local_db',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='root',
                                         port = '3306')


    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for row in csv_data:
        sql = """
        INSERT INTO table_x(Unique_code,city,state,population,Govt) \
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE city = VALUES(city),state = VALUES(state), \
        population = VALUES(population),Govt = VALUES(Govt)"""
        cursor.execute(sql, row)
    connection.commit()
    print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into table_x")
    cursor.close()

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to insert record into table_x table {}".format(error))



finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

But I am getting below error -

```
Failed to insert record into table_x table Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
MySQL connection is closed
```

Please suggest what code changes I can do here to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it convenient to `pip install sqlalchemy`
and then assign `sql = sqlalchemy.Table("""INSERT ...""")`.
Then the quoting syntax for bind parameters will definitely
look like this:

```
... VALUES(:Unique_code,
           :city,
           :state,
           :population,
           :Govt) ...
```

Obtaining input with a [dict reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) may also prove convenient.

The bind param syntax used by your posted code may look like this:

```
... VALUES(%(Unique_code)s,
           %(city)s,
           %(state)s,
           %(population)s,
           %(Govt)s) ...
```

---

Your CREATE TABLE omits a PRIMARY KEY,
so you should probably promote that initial Unique_code column to PK.

Since the posted schema does not have any unique keys being enforced,
the ON DUPLICATE KEY could be removed without changing behavior.
Then you would have a simpler INSERT statement to worry about
during debugging.

Comment: Thanks J_H. I have changed the Unique id to primary key. Now how will rest of the sql (Update part) will look like?